# Как получить разницу дат в SQL запросе

Tags: sql

Я использовал php для вычисления разницы и получал дни, часы и секунды, но появилась необходимость вывести разницу через SQL запрос. Вот запрос, который я использую

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,  NOW(), todo.created)
```

но он возвращает полную разницу в днях, а как мне получить точно секунды, минуты и часы?

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,  NOW(), todo.created) - вместо day поствить: SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.

Answer (score 2):

Первый аргумент в функции TIMESTAMPDIFF может быть

```
SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR.
```

если ответ находится в seconds, тогда

```
save = seconds
days = floor (save / 24*60*60)
save = save - days * 24*60*60
hours = floor (save / 60*60)
save = save - hours * 60*60
...
```

Comment: я понимаю но оно возвращает мене разницу примерно если у нас дата  2015-05-30 15:00:00   и  2015-06-30 15:00:00  получается месяц, то с параметром минут оно возвратит тот же месяц только в минутах

Comment: @modelfak а ожидалось?

Comment: @modelfak я понял. можешь секунды поделить на 24*60*60 - получишь дни и т.д.

Comment: нет нужно именно показать что разница з дня 5 часов и 10 сек

Comment: @modelfak я обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

После получения времени в секундах можно использовать функцию SEC_TO_TIME. Вот пример:

```
select 112378 div (1440*60) days, SEC_TO_TIME(112378 mod (1440*60)) time;
```

Когда СУБД не указана, я предполагаю, что это MySQL. :-)